# On Firefox, when asking to mount an iframe into the DOM, the thread continues to next instruction before waiting for the iframe to be mounted

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

On the following `Stackblitz`...

https://stackblitz.com/edit/it-365-hitpath-pixel-not-firing-through-iframe

I have the following code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

// Important: before trying this, open a Windows console (not Git Bash or Cygwin) and run the following command:
// > C:\Windows\System32\curl.exe --no-keepalive -H "Authorization: Bearer 1cc6274d5c5837e99f494d732ddf376a" "https://api.pipedream.com/sources/dc_XauVB8/sse"

class App extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  handleClick() {
    const iframe_str = '<iframe src="https://93b9e1b4bc322adcd6d208d483bf0c9a.m.pipedream.net" frameborder=0 width=1 height=1></iframe>';
    document.getElementById('pixel').innerHTML = iframe_str;
    window.top.location.href = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=redirection+done';
  }

  render() {
    const style = {
      fontFamily: 'Arial',
      backgroundColor: '#afa',
      padding: '10px',
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <div id="pixel" style={style}>iframe will go here</div><br />
        <input type="button" value="Click" onClick={this.handleClick} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

My issue is between these two lines:

```
document.getElementById('pixel').innerHTML = iframe_str;
window.top.location.href = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=redirection+done';
```

I need to hit an API end point referenced on the `iframe` src.

On `Chrome` it works just fine, it seeams that just before the redirection the `iframe` gets mounted into the DOM and the API end point is hit.

But on `Firefox` it seems that the thread doesn't wait at all and try to redirect right away even before mounting the iframe and hitting the API end point.

I workarounded this by using a `setTimeout` and waiting 1 second before the redirection, but I would like to know:

1. is there better approach for this?
2. why does this issue happen on Firefox and not on Chrome?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1 second is not going to be enough to make sure the iframe loads....  Why even use an iframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will always have a race condition because you do not know how long it will take to render to the DOM and you do not know it the http request made it. Since it is cross domain, you are limited on what you can do with the iframe to tell that it is loaded.

You would be better off with a fetch request if the endpoint supports it.

```
fetch('https://93b9e1b4bc322adcd6d208d483bf0c9a.m.pipedream.net', {
  mode: 'cors',
  cache: 'no-cache'
}).then(() => window.location.href = '//example.com' );
```

Or classic img request

```
const img = new Image();
const redirectIt = () => window.location.href = '//example.com';
img.onload = redirectIt;
img.onerror = redirectIt;
img.src = 'https://93b9e1b4bc322adcd6d208d483bf0c9a.m.pipedream.net';
```

or with [sendBeacon](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon)

```
navigator.sendBeacon('https://93b9e1b4bc322adcd6d208d483bf0c9a.m.pipedream.net');
window.location.href = '//example.com'
```

Comment: thanks @epascarello. I liked the `navigator.sendBeacon` approach!